# N iterations of Mobius Transformations

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T^n$ be defined as $n$ compositions of T. eg: $T^2(z)=T(T(z))$, and $ T^n(z)=T^{n-1}(T(z))$

If T has only one fixed point in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, find a formula for $T^n(z)$ and also determine what happens as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

I've already determined what happens if the fixed point is $\infty$, however I don't know how to proceed if the fixed point is finite (ie, not $\infty$).

Does anyone have any clues with how to proceed?

Comment: Conjugate with another Möbius transformation to move the fixed point to $\infty$.

Comment: Why would we want to fix the point infinity? It doesn't seem like it would help too terribly much

Comment: If $\tilde{T} = S\circ T\circ S^{-1}$ has its fixed point at $\infty$, you know from the first part how $\tilde{T}^n$ looks. Then use $T^n = S^{-1}\circ\tilde{T}^n\circ S$.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting the equation in the form:$ ( T(z) - p1 ) / ( T(z) - p2 ) = k ( z - p1) / ( z - p2 ) $ where T is a Mobius 
transformation, p1 and p2 are fixed points, k is a multiplier , the absolute value of this complex number will tell you where the function goes under iteration . Additionally ,  $ ( T(z) - p1 ) / ( z - p1 ) = k  ( T(z) - p2 ) / ( z - p2 ) $ 
and rewriting, $ r*( T(z) - p1 ) / ( z - p1 ) +  s*( T(z) - p2 ) / ( z - p2 ) = 0   $ we might consider : $ r*( T(z) - p1 ) / ( z - p1 ) +  s*( T(z) - p2 ) / ( z - p2 ) + t*( T(z) - p3 ) / ( z - p3 )= 0   $ where now we have a rational function of degree two whose fixed points are at p1,p2,p3 . We could study the condition for convergence to any of these fixed points, it will be a relation between the complex  numbers r,s,t. And so on, we aren't limited by the degree of the rational function, just keep adding more fixed points and multipliers!